# Cannot figure out How run box\Spout with Windows Subsystem for Linux and composer

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, windows-subsystem-for-linux, spout

I have installed apache2, and php 7.3 sucefully and composer as well,
However the apache2 error.log throws this error:

> [php7:error] [pid 24562] [client ::1:60764] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
>   Error: Class
>   'Box\Spout\Writer\Common\Creator\WriterEntityFactory' not found
>   in /mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/server/index.php:5\nStack trace:\n#0
>   {main}\n  thrown in /mnt/c/Users/Admin/Documents/server/index.php on
>   line 5

I have followed this tutorial from [codecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/setup-a-php-development-environment-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl-9193ff28ae83/) to install everything I need in order to test box/spout as a posible solution to create heavy data files with php.

I hope someone can help me on this I have done some research on internet but I cant find anything that helps.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please show the related code of the index.php file. Did you include composer autoloader?

Comment: @stephangroen you were right thanks 

Answer (score 0):

Turns on that I forget to include **autoloader.php**